# Limit HTTP verbs without redundant config

Tags: nginx

I've got an Elasticsearch cluster plus Logstash and Kibana, and I only want to expose a read-only window into the indexes, with the exception of the index `kibana-int` so that dashboards can be saved.

I've found a suitable ES proxy config, and I've modified it to use `limit_except` to disallow write/modify to other indexes, but much of the config is needlessly duplicated. Is there a cleaner way to define this?

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    server es-01.iad.company.com:9200;
    server es-02.iad.company.com:9200;
}

server {
    listen 9200;
    server_name elasticsearch.proxy;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    location / {
        limit_except GET POST HEAD OPTIONS {
            deny all;
        }
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    }
    location /kibana-int/ {
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways:

#### Solution 1

You could put repeating config into file and `include` it.

Your config:

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    server es-01.iad.company.com:9200;
    server es-02.iad.company.com:9200;
}

server {
    listen 9200;
    server_name elasticsearch.proxy;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    location / {
        limit_except GET POST HEAD OPTIONS {
            deny all;
        }
        include proxy.inc;
    }

    location /kibana-int/ {
        include proxy.inc;
    }
}
```

proxy.inc:

```
proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
```

---

#### Solution 2

Other way is use nginx's directive inheritance.

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    server es-01.iad.company.com:9200;
    server es-02.iad.company.com:9200;
}

server {
    listen 9200;
    server_name elasticsearch.proxy;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;

    location / {
        limit_except GET POST HEAD OPTIONS {
            deny all;
        }
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
    }

    location /kibana-int/ {
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
    }
}
```

---

BTW, your `proxy_pass_header` directives are needless. Nginx proxies almost all headers by default.

Comment: I've eventually got to cram this all into chef so I'm trying to keep the config contained in a single file. Solution 2 has done the trick. Thanks!